# Does there exist the function $f^2(x)\ge f(x+y)\left(f(x)+y \right) $

Tags: functional-equations

> Does there exist the function $f:\mathbb R^+\rightarrow \mathbb R^+$, such that 
>   $$f^2(x)\ge f(x+y)\left(f(x)+y \right) \forall x,y \in \mathbb R^+$$

**My work so far:**

Assume that a function exists. Then $$f(x+y)\le \frac{f^2(x)}{f(x)+y}<f(x).$$
Then this function is strictly decreasing. (And this function is injective).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking logarithms gives
$$
2\log f(x)\geq\log f(x+y)+\log(1+y/f(x))+\log f(x)
$$
After rearranging,
$$
\frac{\log f(x)-\log f(x+y)}{y}\geq\frac{\log(1+y/f(x))}{y},
$$
so after taking limit as $y\rightarrow0$ we get
$$
\frac{-f'(x)}{f(x)}=(-\log f)'(x)\geq\frac{1}{f(x)}.
$$
and so $f'(x)\leq-1$, which contradicts $f:\mathbb{R}^+\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^+$. (As $f$ is decreasing, it is almost everywhere differentiable)

Comment: $f$ may not derivative;

Comment: see the last sentence

Comment: You both could combine your answers and simplify mge's idea a little: There is no need to take logarithms if you use partofsha's first inequality. Then you immediately get $f'(x)\leq -1$ a.e.

Comment: @sranthrop That's right.

Comment: Why $f'(x)\leq-1$ contradicts $f:\mathbb{R}^+\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^+$? Let $f(x)=\frac 1 x$

Comment: @EugenCovaci Are you sure $-1/x^2\leq -1$?

Comment: @mge for $x \in (0,1)$. But it doesn't matter, how do you justify the contradiction?

Comment: It does matter, because if you don't read the statement (the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}^+$, not $(0,1)$) don't expect detailed explanations

Comment: @mge just ignore $f(x)= \frac 1 x$. How do you justify the contradiction?

Comment: @EugenCovaci: Integration over non-degenerate intervals preserves inequalities. In particular, $f'(x)\le-1$ implies, for any $a>0$, $$\int_a^x f'(t)dt=f(x)-f(a)<-x+a.$$

Comment: @VincenzoOliva Your inequality only proves $f(x)<f(a)$. Still I don't see any contradiction.

Comment: @EugenCovaci: Mh? Take $x\to+\infty$.

Comment: @EugenCovaci: Let $a=1$. His inequality shows that $f(x)$ becomes negative for large enough $x$. More intuitively: if the slope is $<-1$ almost everywhere, then the function must decrease at least as fast as $-x$, and  in particular it must eventually cross the x-axis.

Comment: @Samuel  I knew that from the beginning, still I want to see that in the proof. I also can prove that without using integrals.

Comment: @EugenCovaci: But you said you still didn't see any contradiction.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva I don't see it in the proof.

Comment: @EugenCovaci: Lol. True, but we were talking about my inequality, not mge's answer itself. Anyway, it was apparently left to the OP, and apparently he didn't need to ask for clarification. Cheers.

Comment: @VincenzoOliva About your inequality: How do you know $f'$ is Riemann integrable?

Comment: @Samuel I genuinely do not know why  $f′$ is Riemann integrable. Please tell me.

Comment: @EugenCovaci: Perhaps I was a bit sloppy about that. $f'$ is Lebesgue integrable.

Firstly, let us note that if $f$ exists then $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$. Indeed, we have $$0<f(x+y)\le\frac{f^2(x)}{f(x)+y}$$so, taking $y\to+\infty$, the result follows from the squeeze theorem. We already know $f'(x)\le-1$. For a contradiction, suppose $$\liminf_{x\to+\infty}f'(x)=\liminf_{x\to+\infty}\left(\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right)=-\infty.$$

Comment: Then for any $M\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that, for infinitely many $x$, $$\frac{f(x+1/N)-f(x)}{1/N}<-M \\ f(x+1/N)<f(x)-M/N,$$which contradicts $f$ being always positive, as the RHS converges to $-M/N$. Therefore $\lvert f'(x)\rvert$ is bounded, which makes $f$ Lipschitz and thus absolutely continuous. By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for Lebesgue Integration, this is equivalent to $f$ being almost everywhere differentiable (which in this case we already knew), $f'$ being integrable and $\int_a^bf'(x)dx=f(b)-f(a)$.

Comment: @EugenCovaci: Yet, a similar argument applied just to $f'(x)\le-1$ is obviously enough to derive that $f$ ought to become negative, eventually. Integration was just the first thing that naively came to my mind, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that there is a function $f$.then we have
since
$$f^2(x)\ge f(x+y)(f(x)+y)$$
we have
$$f(x)-f(x+y)\ge\dfrac{f(x)y}{f(x)+y}>0$$
which shows that $f$is a strictly decreasing function.Give an $x\in R^{+}$, we choose an $n\in N^{+}$ such $nf(x+1)\ge 1$, then 
$$f\left(x+\dfrac{k}{n}\right)-f\left(x+\dfrac{k+1}{n}\right)\ge\dfrac{f(x+k/n)\cdot\frac{1}{n}}{f(x+\frac{k}{n})+\frac{1}{n}}>\dfrac{1}{2n}$$
summing up these inequalities for $k=0,1,\cdots,n-1$,we have
$$f(x)-f(x+1)>\dfrac{1}{2}$$
take an $m$ such $m\ge 2f(x)$,then
$$f(x)-f(x+m)>\dfrac{m}{2}\ge f(x)$$a contradiction